# Having trouble with search filter for pokemonAPI

Tags: javascript, search, filter

```js
function getHTML() {
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151')
    // return data.map((name) => generateHTML(name));
    // .then((data) => {
    //     newData = data.json();
        // console.log(newData);
        .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((allPokemon) => {
        // generateHTML(data);
        // getPokeData(data);
        allPokemon.results.forEach(function(pokemon) {
            getPokeData(pokemon)
        }
            
        )
    })
}

function getPokeData(pokemon) {
    const url = pokemon.url;
    fetch(url)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    // console.log(url);
    // console.log(pokemon);
    .then(function(pokemon) {
        createPokeCard(pokemon)
        // console.log(data);
    })
}


 function createPokeCard(pokemon) {
    const allPokemonContainer = document.querySelector('.allPokemonContainer');
    const pokeContainer = document.createElement('div');
    pokeContainer.classList.add('pokeContainer');

    // console.log(pokemon.abilities[0]);

    let pokeName = pokemon.name;
    let pokeId = pokemon.id;
    let pokeTypes = pokemon.types[0].type.name;
    // let pokeTypes = pokemon.types;
    let pokeAbilities = pokemon.abilities[0].ability.name;
    // let pokeAbilities = pokemon.abilities;

    const pokemonInnerHTML = `<div class="pokeContainer">
    <img srcset=${`https://nexus.traction.one/images/pokemon/pokemon/${pokeId}.png`}>
       <h3>${pokeName}</h3>
     <p>${pokeId}</p>
      <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="types">
       <h4>Types</h4>
       <ul>
        <li>pokeTypes}</li>
      <li>${pokeTypes}</li>
       </ul>
       </div>
      <div class="Abilities">
      <h4>Abilities</h4>
     <ul>
     <li>pokeAbilities}</li>
      </li>${pokeAbilities}</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>`;

// pokeContainer.append(pokemonInnerHTML);
pokeContainer.innerHTML = pokemonInnerHTML;
allPokemonContainer.append(pokeContainer);

    searchFilter();
 }

const searchFilter = (data) => {

    const searchBar = document.querySelector('.search-bar');

    searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
        const allPokemonContainer = document.querySelector('.allPokemonContainer');
        const pokeContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.pokeContainer');
        const value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
        // console.log(value);
        pokeContainer.forEach((container) => {
            if (searchBar.name.toLowerCase().includes(value)) {
                container.style.display = 'block'
                
            } else {
                container.style.display = 'none'
            }
        })

        // console.log(pokeContainer);
        // pokeContainer.forEach((container) => {
        //     // console.log(container);
        // })
    })
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pokeContainer {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(95, 158, 160);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.menu {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

li.list {
  color: black;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.1rem;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/styles.css">
    <title>Pokemon API</title>
</head>
<body>
        <main>
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <div class="navContainer">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <img src="imgs/pokemon-logo-png (1).png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="navLinks">
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li class="list"><a>Home</a></li>
                            <li class="list"><a>Archive</a></li>
                            <li class="list"><a>Pokemon</a></li>
                            <li class="list"><a>About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" class="search-bar" name="search" placeholder="search pokemon">
            </div>
            <div class="allPokemonContainer">

            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

hey everyone I have been working on this search filter for a few days now and can't seem to figure out what's wrong, using the Pokémon API, I have fetched the data and was able to create the layout with all the information, but the search filter seems not to work correctly, if anyone can help me I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it “seems not to work correctly”? Tell us what you think it should be doing. Tell us what you think it is doing.

Comment: Hey @Corvus I was trying to get the search filter to display the Pokémon that matched the input

Answer (score 0):

the search filter code is missing the search bar input value to be compared with the pokemon names. It should be if

```
(container.querySelector("h3").textContent.toLowerCase().includes(value))
```

instead of if

```
(searchBar.name.toLowerCase().includes(value)).
```